# Is it possible to increment a string or character in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

My output should look like:
1 star(*)
3 stars(***)
4 stars(****)

For example i have code:

```
    char array[] = new char[3];
    char x = '*';
    For (int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        array[i]='*'
        x = x+2;
        system.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible in `char[]` array, you should do it like,

```
String array[] = new String[3];
String x = "*";
for (int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    array[i] = "";
    array[i] = array[i] + x;
    system.out.println(array[i]);
    x = x + "*";
}
```

This will print the output as,

```
*
**
***
```

Comment: My output was:
array[i] + x
array[i] + x
array[i] + x

Comment: @SimonKatimba yes, because I put array[i] + x in `" "` mistakenly. Check my edited answer, it should print the output as I have said

Answer (score 1):

Your array is a char array, so each element contains a single char. Therefore your output will be :

```
*
*
*
```

To get the output you want, you'll need a String array (or no array at all - you can used a nested loop instead).

In addition, `x = x+2;` doesn't do what you think it does. It assigns a new character to `x`. If the initial value of `x` is `'*'`, it will change it to the char whose numeric value is higher by two compared to the numeric value of `'*'`.

Comment: i would love to be able to do that using an array. Is it possible?

Comment: @SimonKatimba Change `char array[] = new char[3];` to `String[] array = new String[3];` and assign the desired values to that array.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an alternative to the already existing answers, it is also possible to just work with `char`. The trick then is to use `System.out.print()` rather than `System.out.println()`. An example:

```
int n = 3;                      //the number of lines you want to print
char x = '*';
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(x);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Note: this is just an alternative to the already proposed solutions

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to change array to String type and concat `*` on it in each level.
Code

```
    String array[] = new String[3];
    char x = '*';
    array[0]=""+x;
    for (int i= 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {

    System.out.println(array[i]);
    if(i!=array.length-1)
    array[i+1]='*'+array[i];
     }
```

And you also have so much compilation error in your code like `For`,`Array`,`system`.

Also check [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/ARpepo)

Answer (score 0):

Considering your out put it can be derived from following

```
String s="*";
StringBuffer sb =new StringBuffer();
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
System.out.println(sb.append(s));
}
```

Output will be 
*
**

---

---

Tc